# Android equivalent for BlackBerry DateTimeUtilities

Tags: java, android, blackberry

Is there an equivalent Android class to the BlackBerry's DateTimeUtilities?  What I really need is DateTimeUtilities.copyCal(source, dest), and I can write it myself, but I really hate writing functions like this only to find it already exists but I just didn't know.  I am aware of clone(), but what I really need is to be able to easily change the timezone of a date without having to worry about DST etc myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFter some further review and fiddling I think this is the easiest way to address this issue for me:

```
public static long applyLocalTimezoneOffsetMillis(long timestampUTC)
{
    long offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(timestampUTC);
    return timestampUTC - offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Joda Time - Java date and time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This would definitely work for me, just a little bit more thorough than I need.